# Must a continuous function mapping rationals to rationals be algebraic?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous (not necessarily analytic) and $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$. Can we conclude that $f$ is algebraic?

Comment: Define $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$, $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in[1,2]$, $f(x)=x^3-6$ for $x\in[2,3]$, ... and keep extending with polynomials with rational coefficients ...

Comment: Short answer: NO - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function